# Разница между web туториалами

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я прошел небезызвестный туториал Djangogirls, написав по нему тот самый блог myfirstblog. После этого я на основе этого туториала написал свой, значительно более простой сайт на другую тематику, добавив от себя некоторые мелочи и по другому реализовав добавление страниц (статей) на сайт. В общем я разобрался с Django на начальном уровне. Теперь в поле моего зрения попала официальная документация Django с идентичным(или нет?) туториалом по созданию web приложения.

Сейчас, я готов вступить в более серьезный web проект на Django и, как можно догадаться, мне хотелось бы узнать **стоит ли проходить туториал из официальной документации, если я прошел обучение по Djangogirls** - есть ли в документации что-то новое и более глубокое(я только про туториал, а не всю документацию, естественно) или же Djangogirls построен поверх туториала из официальной документации и охватывает ее всю?

Comment: Почему бы не пройти даже просто так?

Comment: Я не вижу смысла в повторении одного и того же несколько раз. Если ничего нового нет, то можно спокойно погружаться в более глубокие аспекты документации, а если есть, то я не против пройти что-то новое. Понимаете, не хочется второй раз просидеть пару дней, повторяя все за умными дядей, а на выходе не получить нового опыта работы с фреймворком

Comment: Повторение мать учения и всё такое) Пару дней не так уж и много